# Как решить проблему RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'button_YesorNo' was never awaited?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Столкнулся с проблемой "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'button_YesorNo' was never awaited" в asyncio.

Мне нужно было, чтобы кнопки "да" и "нет" появлялись только у *одного* пользователя, порылся в интернете в поисках готового куска кода, но он выдаёт ошибку. В итоге попытался написать сам.

```
import random
import telebot
import webbrowser
import sqlite3
import time
from telebot import types
import asyncio

db = sqlite3.connect("D:\server.db", check_same_thread=False)
sql = db.cursor()

bot = telebot.TeleBot("...")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_message(message):
    mess = f"{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}"
    if "None" in mess:
        mess = mess.replace("None", "")
        mess = mess.replace(" ", "")
    #chat_title = f"{message.chat.title()}"
    #print(chat_title)
    sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id BIGINT,
        progress INT
    )""")
    db.commit()
    Id = int(f"{message.from_user.id}")
    check = 0
    for ws in sql.execute(f"SELECT Id FROM users WHERE Id == {Id}"):
        pe = str(ws)
        pe = pe.replace("(", "")
        pe = pe.replace(")", "")
        pe = pe.replace(",", "")
        check = int(pe)
        if check == Id:
            obj = time.localtime()
            t = time.asctime(obj)
            print(f"{t} Id: {Id} - регистрация")
    if check == 0:
        sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (Id, progress) VALUES ('{Id}', '0')")
        db.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы можете ввести /help, чтобы узнать о возможностях бота.")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["сброс"])
async def button_YesorNo(message: types.Message):
    Id = f"{message.from_user.id}"
    mess = f"{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}"
    if "None" in mess:
        mess = mess.replace("None", "")
        mess = mess.replace(" ", "")
    markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1, selective=True)
    buttons = ['///да', '///нет']
    markup.add(*buttons)
    await message.reply(f"{mess}, ты точно уверен, что хочешь обнулить свой прогресс? Нажми на кнопку с ответом.", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def message_reply(message):
    Id = f"{message.from_user.id}"
    mess = f"{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}"
    if "None" in mess:
        mess = mess.replace("None", "")
        mess = mess.replace(" ", "")
    if message.text=="///да":
        dell = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{mess}, твой прогресс обнулён!", reply_markup=dell)
        sql.execute(f"UPDATE users SET progress = 0 WHERE Id == {Id}")
        db.commit()
    if message.text=="///нет":
        de = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

db.close()
```

С asyncio вообще не знаком, в интернете искал, слишком заумно написано, главную суть уловить так и не удалось, перевод документации в лучших традициях гугл корявый.

Если кто знает как решить данную проблему, распишите пожалуйста для меня чайника саму суть проблемы и как Вы дошли до решения.

Comment: Вы где-то запускаете функцию `button_YesorNo` вручную?

Comment: Вручную я только в телеграмм боте пишу "/сброс", остальное, теоритически, должно происходить само

Comment: А покажите весь лог ошибки

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 98
    task(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'button_YesorNo' was never awaited

Comment: Я уверен там не одна строчка. Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте ВЕСЬ лог, пожалуйста

Comment: Нет, именно эту ошибку выдаёт программа, больше АБСОЛЮТНО ничего нет)

Comment: Может тогда больше кода дадите ибо я не вижу в нем причины этой ошибки

Comment: Как-то так, все остальные команды работают как надо, эта тоже до доработки отрабатывала правильно, но мне не нужно, чтобы кнопки были видны всему чату. Поэтому взялся за переделку. Некоторые моменты тоже подвергнутся ребилду, но позже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в этой строке

```
await message.reply(f"{mess}, ты точно уверен, что хочешь обнулить свой прогресс? Нажми на кнопку с ответом.", reply_markup=markup)
```

У телебота такого нет `message.reply` только через обьект бота.
Но что важнее он не асинхронный, так что и `await` ему не нужен

```
bot.reply_to(message, "text")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает как нужно) Чрезвычайно Вам благодарен за помощь