# Проблема в удалении записи в sqlalchemy2

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, asyncio, sqlalchemy, aiogram-3.x

Пишу ТГ бота:

1. sqlalchemy(v.2) + aiogram(v.3) и asyncio...
2. Задача состоит на данный момент в том, чтобы сделать метод удаления записи из базы данных, по параметру, в который передаётся "id" записи...
3. На данный момент реализован такой метод:

```
...
# Удаляет из БД запись посредством параметра 'data' - это 'id' записи
@staticmethod
async def del_item(data):
    async with async_session() as conn:
        prod = await conn.delete(Product).where(Product.id == data)
```

4. Данный обработчик снизу, по нажатию на кнопку, должен активировать метод удаления, передав пока что тестово "id" например "3"(далее собираюсь реализовывать функционал удаления для обработчика, он должен захватывать id товара, который есть у каждого выдаваемого товара и по нажатию кнопки 'удалить'(она есть под каждым товаром), удалять этот товар...).

```
...
# Обработчик показывает корзину
@router.message(F.text == smile_dict[4])
async def basket_saler(message: Message):
    await Tools.del_item(3)
    await message.answer("Товар удалён!!!")
...
```

Проблема в ошибках, который то и дело мне выдаёт интерпретатор, какие бы методы, я не пробовал... Например:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncSession.delete' was never awaited
  return True  # because update was processed but unsuccessful
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как решить проблему RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'button\_YesorNo' was never awaited?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473658/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-runtimewarning-coroutine-button-yesorno-was-never-awaited)